# Impersonation of active directory user in vb.net

Tags: asp.net, active-directory, impersonation

I've never programmed the active directory but I would like to do the following:

1. On the asp.net site, login using a valid active directory username and password.If the login is valid, redirect to a page to do some actions.
2. In a related task, but not part of part 1, unlock an account or change the password of an active directory account.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1.) You should setup your web.config to use Forms authentication. The Membership provider should be set to ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider. You can use the built-in login control.

2.) You'd need a Active Directory user who has the specific rights you ask for: unlock accounts, changing passwords. When you perform one of those functions for a AD-user, you need to impersonate the account which ASP executes as to the Active Directory user which has the privileges (to change passwords or unlock accounts).

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to use 'advapi32.dll' to impersonate a different user on the server side.

Grab the sample code off the bottom of the page.

I didn’t want to just copy his code here.

http://csharptuning.blogspot.com/2007/06/impersonation-in-c.html

One cavet with Impersonation though is that the computer doing the impersonation needs to be on the same domain as the user that your impersonating